# The right place to put the Styles and Templates for a WPF project

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF project in MVVM Architecture and I override almost every default style or template. Until now I put all the styles in the App.Resources but it's getting quite messy... Is there a better way to organize those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to split your App.xaml into multiple pieces and group your resources the way you prefer as most convenient. Just refer them from main app resources, something like that:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ... something still sits here...
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesHere.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesThere.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesEtc.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Just do not forget about declaration/reference precedence: a resource dictionary can not refer to something that declared in a next resource dictionary. So it can be worth to extract general declarations first dictionary, then put all dependent staff in next dictionaries.